# WatchOS establish server connection

Tags: swift, watchos, starscream

I have a client - server IOS application. In addition, I need to write an application for it on WatchOS. So I have 2 questions:

1. When I send a command from Apple Watch, do I need to connect to the server from the watch or transfer information to the IOS application and connect to the server from the phone?
2. If I have to connect to the server with an IOS application, then how can I connect in background mode?

As an example, you can take any messenger, for example Telegram
If I reply to a message with AppleWatch, how is the message being sent to the server (Via iPhone  or directly via AppleWatch)
For connection to the server, I use the "Starscream" framework

Maybe I don't understand something, but Apple made it impossible to establish a connection in background mode

I would be grateful if you tell me or provide examples and articles, so that I could understand what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple Watch apps can connect directly to servers using [URLSession](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession) ... no need to go via the phone.

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession/processing_url_session_data_task_results_with_combine) is an example on using `URLSession` in Combine, which is the "latest and greatest" way of doing things.

Otherwise [this](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/sending-and-receiving-codable-data-with-urlsession-and-swiftui) example shows using it in a more conventional way, with the bonus of SwiftUI.

Otherwise

Comment: Maybe, do you have more actual example, not from 2014 and ObjC? Thanks

Comment: Added more recent examples.